# Checking a lists for values to see if they exist

Tags: python, algorithm

I have this code that's pretty obviously a GPA calculator but its only a weighted GPA calculator. When I test the code it works fine with the values

```
[A, B, C, D, F]
```

But when I want to test it with values such as

```
[A+, B, B-, Z]
```

I don't know how to account for the grades that are not actually in the list. I need the code to return None if it is tested with such letters. I have tried using "if" to do it like I did with

```
if grades == []:
    return None
if credit_worth ==[]:
    return None
```

But I just cant get it, here is the rest of the code:

```
def gpa_calculator(grades, credit_worth):

    gpa_value = {'A': 4.0,'B': 3.0,'C': 2.0,'D': 1.0,'F': 0.0,
                  'a': 4.0, 'b': 3.0, 'c': 2.0, 'd': 1.0, 'f': 0.0}
    total_credits = 0

    if grades == []:
        return None
    if credit_worth == []:
        return None
    for grade, credit in zip(grades, credit_worth):
        total_credits += gpa_value[grade] * credit



    GPA = total_credits / sum(credit_worth)
    return GPA
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this line in the for loop:

```
if grade not in gpa_value.keys():
    return None
```

Comment: is there another way to do it, I have not learned `.keys`  yet?

Comment: .keys() is a standard dict method to fetch the list of keys in your dictionary. Any reason why you don't want to use it?

Comment: Not really, I just prefer to use code I know so I don't get confused. But you just explained it to my so I'm good. Thank you.